# Hbase master keeps dying, claims a hbase:namespace already exists

Tags: hadoop, hbase

In todays episode of hbase is bringing me to my wits end we have an issue where the hbase master starts and then very quickly dies.  My master log is like so:

```
2014-06-20 12:52:40,469 FATAL [master:hdev01:60000] master.HMaster: Master serve
r abort: loaded coprocessors are: []
2014-06-20 12:52:40,470 FATAL [master:hdev01:60000] master.HMaster: Unhandled ex
ception. Starting shutdown.
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableExistsException: hbase:namespace
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.handler.CreateTableHandler.prepare(Cre
ateTableHandler.java:120)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.TableNamespaceManager.createNamespaceT
able(TableNamespaceManager.java:232)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.TableNamespaceManager.start(TableNames
paceManager.java:86)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.initNamespace(HMaster.java:106
2)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.finishInitialization(HMaster.j
ava:926)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.run(HMaster.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2014-06-20 12:52:40,473 INFO  [master:hdev01:60000] master.HMaster: Aborting
2014-06-20 12:52:40,473 DEBUG [master:hdev01:60000] master.HMaster: Stopping ser
vice threads
2014-06-20 12:52:40,473 INFO  [master:hdev01:60000] ipc.RpcServer: Stopping serv
er on 60000
2014-06-20 12:52:40,473 INFO  [CatalogJanitor-hdev01:60000] master.CatalogJanito
r: CatalogJanitor-hdev01:60000 exiting
2014-06-20 12:52:40,473 INFO  [hdev01,60000,1403283149823-BalancerChore] balance
r.BalancerChore: hdev01,60000,1403283149823-BalancerChore exiting
2014-06-20 12:52:40,474 INFO  [RpcServer.listener,port=60000] ipc.RpcServer: Rpc
Server.listener,port=60000: stopping
2014-06-20 12:52:40,474 INFO  [RpcServer.responder] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.res
ponder: stopped
2014-06-20 12:52:40,474 INFO  [master:hdev01:60000] master.HMaster: Stopping inf
oServer
2014-06-20 12:52:40,474 INFO  [RpcServer.responder] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.res
ponder: stopping
2014-06-20 12:52:40,474 INFO  [master:hdev01:60000.oldLogCleaner] cleaner.LogCle
aner: master:hdev01:60000.oldLogCleaner exiting
2014-06-20 12:52:40,475 INFO  [hdev01,60000,1403283149823-ClusterStatusChore] ba
lancer.ClusterStatusChore: hdev01,60000,1403283149823-ClusterStatusChore exiting

2014-06-20 12:52:40,476 INFO  [master:hdev01:60000.oldLogCleaner] master.Replica
tionLogCleaner: Stopping replicationLogCleaner-0x246ba2ab1e4001c, quorum=hdev02:
5181,hdev01:5181,hdev03:5181, baseZNode=/hbase
2014-06-20 12:52:40,479 INFO  [master:hdev01:60000] mortbay.log: Stopped SelectC
hannelConnector@0.0.0.0:16010
2014-06-20 12:52:40,478 INFO  [master:hdev01:60000.archivedHFileCleaner] cleaner
.HFileCleaner: master:hdev01:60000.archivedHFileCleaner exiting
2014-06-20 12:52:40,483 INFO  [master:hdev01:60000.oldLogCleaner] zookeeper.ZooK
eeper: Session: 0x246ba2ab1e4001c closed
2014-06-20 12:52:40,484 INFO  [master:hdev01:60000-EventThread] zookeeper.Client
Cnxn: EventThread shut down
2014-06-20 12:52:40,589 DEBUG [master:hdev01:60000] catalog.CatalogTracker: Stop
ping catalog tracker org.apache.hadoop.hbase.catalog.CatalogTracker@f3f348b
2014-06-20 12:52:40,591 INFO  [master:hdev01:60000] client.HConnectionManager$HC
onnectionImplementation: Closing zookeeper sessionid=0x246ba2ab1e4001b
2014-06-20 12:52:40,592 INFO  [master:hdev01:60000] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session
: 0x246ba2ab1e4001b closed
2014-06-20 12:52:40,592 INFO  [master:hdev01:60000-EventThread] zookeeper.Client
Cnxn: EventThread shut down
2014-06-20 12:52:40,695 INFO  [hdev01,60000,1403283149823.splitLogManagerTimeout
Monitor] master.SplitLogManager$TimeoutMonitor: hdev01,60000,1403283149823.split
LogManagerTimeoutMonitor exiting
2014-06-20 12:52:40,696 INFO  [master:hdev01:60000] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session
: 0x246ba2ab1e4001a closed
2014-06-20 12:52:40,696 INFO  [main-EventThread] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThre
ad shut down
2014-06-20 12:52:40,696 INFO  [master:hdev01:60000] master.HMaster: HMaster main
 thread exiting
2014-06-20 12:52:40,697 ERROR [main] master.HMasterCommandLine: Master exiting
java.lang.RuntimeException: HMaster Aborted
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.startMaster(HMaster
CommandLine.java:194)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandL
ine.java:135)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLi
ne.java:126)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:2803)
```

I thought this might be some remnant of an old run so I deleted the files in hbases data directory, the zookeepers data directory and my hdfs.  I still got the same error.  Strangely my HMaster popper back up again temporarily when I ran stop-hbase.sh although there wasn't much I could do with it.

My Hbase version is 98.3 and my hadoop is 2.2.0.  My hbase-site.comf is

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>hbase.master</name>
  <value>hdev01:60000</value>
  <description>The host and port that the HBase master runs at.
                                                     A value of 'local' runs the master and a regionserver
                                                     in a single process.
                                </description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
  <value>hdfs://hdev01:9000/hbase</value>
  <description>The directory shared by region servers.</description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
  <value>true</value>
  <description>The mode the cluster will be in. Possible values are
                                false: standalone and pseudo-distributed setups with managed
                                Zookeeper true: fully-distributed with unmanaged Zookeeper
                                Quorum (see hbase-env.sh)
                                </description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
  <value>5181</value>
  <description>Property from ZooKeeper's config zoo.cfg.
    The port at which the clients will connect.
    </description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>zookeeper.session.timeout</name>
  <value>10000</value>
  <description></description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hbase.client.retries.number</name>
  <value>10</value>
  <description></description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
  <value>hdev01,hdev02,hdev03</value>
  <description>Comma separated list of servers in the ZooKeeper Quorum. For example, "host1.mydomain.com,host2.mydomain.com". By default this is set to localhost for local and pseudo-distributed modes of operation. For a fully-distributed setup, this should be set to a full list of ZooKeeper quorum servers. If
                                     HBASE_MANAGES_ZK is set in hbase-env.sh
                                     this is the list of servers which we will start/stop
                                     ZooKeeper on.
                </description>
</property>
</configuration>
```

EDIT
Attempted hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.hbck.OfflineMetaRepair, my error now is  `HBase file layout needs to be upgraded. You have version null and I want version 8. Is your hbase.rootdir valid? If so, you may need to run 'hbase hbck -fixVersionFile'`
Which is unhelpful since without a master hbck will not actually run.
Edited edit
I nuked and restarted my dfs and then tried repairing and starting things again, i am now back where i started.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

hbase namespace is the internal namespace HBAse uses for its own management tables. Try to run the offline repair tool 
from the $HBASE_HOME directory:

```
 ./bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.hbck.OfflineMetaRepair
```

Comment: That changed my error atleast.  Now it tells me WARNING! HBase file layout needs to be upgraded.  You have version null and I want version 8.  Is your hbase.rootdir valid?  If so, you may need to run 'hbase hbck -fixVersionFile'.
which is unhelpful since I lack a master to run hbck on

Comment: And after nuking my dfs and then rerunning the offline repair tool i am back where i started

Comment: Well you can also login to zookeeper and remove the /hbase dir (hbase zkcli and rmr the /hbase dir - be careful not to delete anything else)

Comment: So in conclusion I have tried every way to turn it off and on.  Thankfully this one seems to have worked, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @arnon-rotem-gal-oz - Removing /hbase znode would result in all Hbase data being lost too including tables, region servers, etc.? Or would Hbase Master be able to build that information up and there is no data loss?

Answer (score 2):

su - hdfs

hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.hbck.OfflineMetaRepair

(restart the hbase master.if still u are facing issue then do following)

zookeeper-client (enter)

rmr /hbase

quit

Then restart the hbase master service

Comment: What if Zookeeper is internally managed by Hbase i.e HBASE_manages_ZK=true. Then how to delete the data inside zookeeper?                                                                                               I tried the repair command, but no use.Same error

Answer (score 1):

@shash:
When HBase manages ZooKeeper( i.e. HBASE_manages_ZK=true), the command to access and clean hbase data is :
**hbase zkcli**. Afterwards you clean hbae using the command **rmr /hbase**, then you **quit**.